# how to set switch button to manual mode in android

Tags: android

My application contains two activities :

First activity contains :
1.different types of modes 
2.intensity
3.CCT

Inside of the if condition not going control.if am selecting the seekbar the it should return true.if it is true means should move to next activity.

can any one help me

```
mColorTemp = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.intensity1);
mScheduler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean swichAction=false;

            if(mColorTemp.isSelected()==true){
                swichAction=true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SchedulerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("swichAction",swichAction);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            }


  });
```

Along with this i have button named as Scheduler.
Now am not selecting anyone from first activity and press on the scheduler then it will move to the second activity.In the second activity should show labeled switch on to auto.

If am selecting anyone from first activity then should turn to Manual

Second Activity contains :

Labeled switch in that text contains Auto/Manual

Can any one please help me how to do it.

Comment: try passing data in intent.putExtra

Comment: can you give some more explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `mColorTemp.isSelected()` to do that. Instead, you has to plug a listener on value changed. If value is changed by user, manual mode can be activated.

```
mColorTemp.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {       

  @Override       
  public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {      
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
  }       

  @Override       
  public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {     
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
  }       

  @Override       
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {     
    mManualActivated = true;
  }
}
```

Then, you can use `Extras` to pass variables from an Activity to another.

**How to "put"**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SchedulerActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);  
intent.putExtra("extra_mode", mManualActivated);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, to retrieve the value, add this in the `SchedulerActivity.onCreate()` :

```
Boolean manualActivated = false;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    manualActivated = extras.getBoolean("extra_mode");
}
```

Comment: _"If am selecting anyone from first activity then should turn to Manual"_ it means that you're able to determine the value you have to pass

Comment: for eg: suppose am selecting image then press on scheduler button it should move to second activity .In the second activity labeled switch should turn to manual

Comment: Yes understood. Before displaying the second Activity, you have to detect a selection, right ? Is there a problem ?

Comment: Are you able to listen to these selections ? If so, you have to store in a Boolean variable for example if user has made a selection. If yes, you can tell that it is a "manual" mode

Comment: i have written like this have a mode named as classic.if(mclassic.isSelected ==true){mode =Manual}

Comment: ok, great. So, you can pass the Boolean value in the `Extra` part of the intent, instead of passing as String value as I first proposed

Comment: Burno if am selecting any one of the fields means how to do

Comment: We are turning in a round. I don't know how your screen is made so I can't help you more. I gave you a solution to pass arguments from one activity to another. If you want us to help you with storing the fact that the user selects something, please be more precise and edit your question

Comment: how to check if it multiple actions

Comment: add a listener on each actions, with the same stored boolean value